# how to select the max value in mysql in varchar field

Tags: mysql

I have one mysql table, in that table contain varchar field. I want to get the max value from the table.

**My Table -**
[image]

**My SQL QUERY -**

```
SELECT Max(CAST(test as SIGNED)) as a FROM testtable;
```

**Wanted Output-**

G450

how to select the max value in mysql in varchar field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your data always has single character followed by integer, you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE substring(test,2)=(SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(test,2) AS SIGNED)) FROM testtable);
```

This will return all rows with the character followed by the max integer - i.e. if you have G540 and X540, it'll return both.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('G' , MAX(0+SUBSTRING(test,2))) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Can you please provide more commentary as to what your answer is doing? This helps the OP to learn how the fix works.